# How can I Merge an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-apps-script

I was wondering how i could merge these two objects retrieve the tag values and store them in an array. This data is also coming from a json response so incoming data should be pushed onto the end of the new array.

so it would look something like this
["2011 LDI", "2012 LDI"]

array with incoming data:
["2011 LDI", "2012 LDI","2013 LDI"]

Here is what I am getting back in my console.log:

```
[19-08-25 21:58:32:055 PDT] []
[19-08-25 21:58:32:056 PDT] []
```

Here are the two objects of arrays i am trying to merge:

```
 {date_added=2019-08-26 04:19:00.112083, tag=LDI 2011}
   {date_added=2019-08-26 04:19:00.112089, tag=LDI 2012}
```

and I want it to look like this

[LDI 2011, LDI 2012]

and how I am trying to do it.

```
  var tagtest = [];
  var tags = message.student_detail.student_tags,
      i = 0,
      len = tags.length;
  for (i; i < len; i++) {
    var obj = tags[i];
    for (a in obj) {
    }
    Array.prototype.push(tags, tagtest);
    Logger.log(tagtest)
  }
```

Comment: Can you add an example of what you want the result to look like? Can you also update the question so that the objects are valid js?

Comment: Hey @Spangle I have just added what I would like the result to look like,

Comment: "and I want it to look like this [LDI 2011, LDI 2012]" ==> That also is not valid Javascript, and it is an array, not an object. Are you wanting to create an array that just contains the LDI values?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly right, sorry for being a pain, i'm quite new to this, I am trying to merge the objects of array's into one array containg the LDI values I should re clarify*

Comment: Are you sure that is what the object looks like too? Is it in a string? Because it is not formatted correctly. There should be no =, it should be a : and the values should be wrapped in ""

Answer (score 1):

Based on your desired output (`[LDI 2011, LDI 2012]`), You may want the only `tag` values from the array, If this is what you are looking for then `.map()` will help you

```js
 const array = [
   {
    date_added: '2019-08-26', 
    tag: 'LDI 2011' 
   }, 
   {
   date_added: '2019-08-26', 
   tag: 'LDI 2012' 
  }];
 const tags = array.map((r) => {
   const chunk = r.tag.split(' ');
   return `${chunk[1]} ${chunk[0]}`;
 } );
 console.log(tags);
```

Comment: I should have noted that there could be more then those two values coming in as it is coming in from a JSON response so there could be more than just those two values

Comment: Yes, there are objects with key-value pairs, but as you mentioned you want `[LDI 2011, LDI 2012]`, That's why  `.map()` coming in the picture

Comment: If you want all key-values from an array, then no operation needs to be done

Comment: AH I see, and would  I replace the data value with the  message.student_detail.student_tags 

for all the key-values which come through?

Comment: Edit your question and put your outcome whatever you want

Comment: What do you want to replace with whom?

Comment: That does not make much of a difference, are you getting an array or an object? 'array with incoming data: ["2011 LDI", "2012 LDI","2013 LDI"]' However you said you were getting JSON and also have an object??

Comment: It seems to be you want to convert  `["2011 LDI"]` to `["LDI 2012"] `, is that what you want ?

Answer (score 0):

A for in loop is a great way to work with objects. I updated the code above so that it was actually an array of objects, not an error. See below :)

```js
var data = [{date_added: "2019-08-26 04:19:00.112083", tag: "LDI 2011"}, 
{date_added: "2019-08-26 04:19:00.112089", tag: "LDI 2012"}];

var newArr = [];
for(var item in data) {
    newArr.push(data[item].tag);
}

console.log(newArr);
```